# How to assign a return value from API call to class member variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api

I have a class that has a member-variable **name** and a function **getdata()**.
The function makes an API call and assigns the value it receives to the member variable

```
class Person
{
constructor()
    {
    this.name = this.getdata();
    }
getdata()
    {
    $.ajax({
          url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            this.name = data;
          }
        });
    }

}
```

But the value is not assigned.

I have also tried fetch:

```
class Person
{
constructor()
    {
    this.name = this.getdata();
    }
getdata()
    {

    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/').then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function(j) {
            this.name = j                   
    });
    }

}
```

But it does not identify this inside the then function

Comment: I have also tried using return statement instead of this.name inside the success blocks

Comment: To 'close' voters:  This might well be a duplicate of something else.  But it's asking something different from the linked question, and the solution there does not answer this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at [a question on the use of `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/) in JS.  The `this` you assign to in the function is not what you're expecting.

The quickest fix is to do something like

```
// ...
getData: function() {
  const self = this;
  fetch(...).then(...
    self.name = j
  )
}
```

But using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) would also fix this.

Comment: I do understand your point, that when the fetch success function is called, the class object loses scope. however, that's my exact question. how do i point to the class object in the fetch function? And if that is not possible, how do I return the value to assign it to the class member variable

Comment: I believe my (untested) answer does exactly what you're saying.  (Or perhaps your comment came in before my edit was finished?)

Comment: yes, I wrote that before the edit was finished.
Great, the solution worked, Thanks

Comment: Sorry, simply accidentally pushed the submit button before I was finished.  Thought my edit would get in soon enough not to mark it as such.  Oh well.